# Sentence ending at に what means?

Tags: meaning, particle-に

In the sentence

> つい先日も、今のバイトもキツイとか辞めるとか、そんなことばっかり言ってたくせ**に**。

Why is the に at the end? What can it mean?

Comment: Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/29333/9831 / https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/56577/9831

Comment: Well... That actually solves it! (Bottom one (right cause I'm on phone))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is ~くせに construction. [Learn about it here](http://maggiesensei.com/2013/09/24/%E3%80%9C%E3%81%8F%E3%81%9B%E3%81%AB-kuseni-from-facebook-mini-lessons/)